# Is Hulu hacked? Or is it my Mac browser?

Tags: google-chrome, virus, hulu

Do you know why I'm directed to a url on piratenpartij.nl when I try to play Jon Stewart on Hulu.com?

I can't figure out if my Mac has a virus, or if it's something on my Chrome browser, or if there's an issue with Hulu.

This is the url I'm sent to:
www.hulu.com.proxy.piratenpartij.nl/watch/385839?c=Comedy/Satire#x-0,vepisode,1,0

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove/disable all Chrome extensions, plugins, user scripts, etc. and reloaded the page? Does it happen in other browsers? On other user accounts? Have you set up any kind of privacy proxy in the past?

Comment: Also, try Safari, or Firefox. Same behavior?

Comment: It looks like you are using a proxy. I can promise you one thing. The fact its a .nl domain and Hulu is an American company means that its not actually Hulu trying to direct you to that domain. Unless you show us your address bar its not possible to say whats going on.  I can tell one additional thing, Hulu.com has not been hacked, this is something unique to your user experience.

Comment: Do the videos work?

Comment: @liberta The video didn't work. I got an error telling me to try again.

Comment: @RichHomolka It doesn't come up in Safari. I don't have FF on this machine.

Comment: I just realized this is happening to me as well. I use ubuntu Chrome, chromium, and Firefox. They all seem to be doing it.

Comment: Fixed it, see my post below.

Answer (score 4):

You, nor Hulu have been hacked. proxy.piratenpartij.nl is a proxy that has been set up by the Piratenpartij, the dutch branch of the [Pirate Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_Party) (of Pirate Bay fame.) This proxy has been set up in defiance of a local ruling to block access to the Pirate Bay website and also to allow dutch internet users to access content that has been blocked from them based on their geographical location, such as Hulu which is only available to the US. [Source](http://tweakers.net/nieuws/81415/piratenpartij-hoeft-generieke-proxy-niet-offline-te-halen.html): (in dutch) "Piratepartij cannot be forced to bring generic proxy offline".

So the site's not malicious but the question remains why you have landed on a page that redirects links to the dutch proxy. Could it be that you've searched for something on the internet, or followed a link meant for non-US users, and landed on the proxied Hulu site ?

Comment: The part about the Pirate Bay proxy makes sense. The domain of the page I was on was hulu.com. So I'm not sure why I was being redirected. For some reason, I can't reproduce this now.

Comment: This is actually happening to me right now with Daily Show, and Googling around led me here. Very strange.

Comment: I switched to private browsing, and it stopped taking me through that proxy link. But when I went back to normal browsing to try and disable plugins one-by-one to single out the trouble making plugin, I couldn't reproduce the problem!

Comment: @Gisborne - This indicates you are being detected as a user in another country.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to see if you're not a continuing victim of the DNS worm that was going around?! The FBI just recently stopped DNS changer services on July 9, 2012 so hopefully that's not the reason. (For more, here's a link to read: http://digitalsaliva.com/internet-shutdown-9july-dns-changer/ )

If you're sure that's not the reason then you might want to adjust your router and browser's DNS service to someone like OpenDNS (http://www.opendns.com/) assuming you're on your own account and not in a dorm setting or connected to free WiFi or something.

But most of all you may want to check your browsers settings. For example, you may want to adjust your browsers ability to resolve web addresses using a web service, predicting network actions, or using a prediction service and disable them. These are advanced settings in Chrome just in case you're wondering. But there are similar settings like that in most of the other major browsers too. These things may be more convenient but they are not without risk. So I suggest turning them off.

Comment: If he was infected with the worm in question, he likely wouldn't be able to access any website, since he wouldn't be able to connect to anything.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed the issue on my end. I just deleted all personal data. cookies, cache and downloaded items. Try this and report back.

Do you happen do you use the ad-block extension or TOR?

Comment: The use of TOR would cause a problem like, since this proxy should only be used, if the user is detected as being in a country not supported by Hulu.

Comment: I use AdBlock on Chrome. Why do you think it's connected to this issue? What do you think is causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure I have not been able to replicate the issue since clearing personal data. I believe it was a cookie we may have picked up from somewhere. This is why the problem existed in two browsers for me.

Comment: I suspected adblock is because it's the only extension I was using. I'm usually fairly cautious online. SO tt was most likely a cookie. Some form of cookie poisoning I'm certain of that.